# floated div aligned with contenteditable caret position

Tags: html, css, contenteditable, caret

I have this markup:

**HTML**

```
<div class="figure">
   <img src="path/to/img" alt=""></div>
<div class="ce" contenteditable="true">
    <p></p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.figure {
    width: 540px;
    height: 540px;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
}
.figure img {
    height: 540px;
}
.ce {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 30px;
}
```

As you can test in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5bmmskwy/) , when you place the caret inside the `contenteditable` the `caret` is above the `div.figure`, at the left. When you start tiping the caret get placed right to the `div.figure` and that is what I want. 
My goal is to place, on focus, the caret in the exactly position that it takes when you start typing. 
How can I achieve this? 
I tried with `display: inline-block` on `.ce` `div` but it takes me other problems.